# how to run many transactions in an MS Access database in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to develop a software that will later be used by a big company which means a lot of database transactions will be made by the end users using the system.How do I ensure the software will not crash especially when making transactions?I have experienced this problem before and I dont know the way forward.Please help

Comment: First, do not use MS Access. Use SQL Server instead. MS Access is not designed to reliably handle multiple users.

Comment: Agreed. SQL Express is free and MUCH more reliable.

Comment: thanks guyz.I will have to transfer my database if thats tha case